# How to change the deafult template in Wordpress plugin

Tags: plugins, templates

I have this plugin: [Simple Job Board](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/simple-job-board/) When I view a job offer I see the default view from my theme. But in page attribute I have a lot templates. but if I change, nothing happens. It is possible to change it by using functions.php ?

Kind regards

--edit
Or how to change the default template off all page in wordpress ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your plugin question, you need to contact the plugin's support guys. Plugin questions are not within scope here.

For information about templates, start here to gain knowledge on how they work: https://codex.wordpress.org/Templates. Templates are part of the theme, so to change the template, you have to change the template used by the theme.

But you don't want to change theme templates, you want to create a Child Theme that uses your current theme. Put your modified templates in the Child Theme, so any theme updates don't bork your custom templated.

Learn about Child Themes here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes .

Comment: Hey, @Rick Hellewell, in some cases he really doesn't need to alter the theme at all, just the plugin.

Comment: There were two parts to his question; and two parts to my answer. 1st: plugin support via developer; not here. 2nd: how to change the default template (best done via a Child Theme). Both questions answered in my answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> It is possible to change it by using functions.php ?

This is very general question. And general questions need general answers. Right :). So it is possible to do many things from functions.php file.

When plugins like your is in question it is recommended to use plugins hooks and actions to alter the layout, and you can use the `function.php` to do so.

If the plugin doesn't provide hooks you need to use [WordPress hooks for that](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Hooks).

Answer (score -1):

Copy plugin template files in the theme folder. And update it as you wanted. That will not effect on plugin updates and plugin files